# Spring data - $regex - is there an or?

Tags: mongodb, spring-data

I use this method in order to find products:

```
@Query("{ 'name' : { $regex: ?0 }, 'number' : { $regex: ?1 } }")
List<Product> findProductByRegex(final String searchString, final String number);
```

I can not find products where name or number contains a term.
Is there an or conjunction with @Query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For injection you need to wrap your current query with `$or:[]`, so it will look like this

```
@Query("{ $or: [ { 'name' : { $regex: ?0 }, 'number' : { $regex: ?1 } } ] }")
```